# Bootstrap date-picker not being set

Tags: html, forms, twitter-bootstrap, date, laravel

I'm using Laravel's `Illuminate` to get a date forum.

```
<div class="form-group">
    {!! Form::label('published_at', 'Publish On:') !!}
    {!! Form::input('date', 'published_at') !!}
</div>
```

My page source is this:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="published_at">Publish On:</label>
    <input name="published_at" type="date" id="published_at">
</div>
```

I'm picking up the date through `Eloquent` like so:

```
public function setPublishedAtAttribute($date){
    $this->attributes['published_at'] = Carbon::parse($date);
}
```

For some reason, changing the date is not changing, only picking up the current date. Is this a Laravel or Bootstrap issue?

EDIT
Tried debugging the form. This is my http response:

```
Remote Address:[::1]:8000
Request URL:http://localhost:8000/articles
Request Method:POST
Status Code:200 OK
Response Headers
view source
Cache-Control:no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate
Cache-Control:post-check=0, pre-check=0
Connection:close
Content-type:text/html
Expires:Sat, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT
Host:localhost:8000
Last-Modified:Mon, 17 Aug 2015 04:28:25 GMT
Pragma:no-cache
X-Powered-By:PHP/5.5.27
Request Headers
view source
Accept:text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8
Cache-Control:max-age=0
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Length:101
Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Cookie:[removed by me]
Host:localhost:8000
Origin:http://localhost:8000
Referer:http://localhost:8000/articles/create
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests:1
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/44.0.2403.130 Safari/537.36
Form Data
view source
view URL encoded
_token:[removed by me]
title:date3
body:asdfasdfasdf
published_at:2015-08-26
```

Not sure how I would debug this but this is the script preview. I have bootstrap locally, not a CDN.

```
<script> Sfdump = window.Sfdump || (function (doc) { var refStyle = doc.createElement('style'), rxEsc = /([.*+?^${}()|\[\]\/\\])/g, idRx = /\bsf-dump-\d+-ref[012]\w+\b/, keyHint = 0 <= navigator.platform.toUpperCase().indexOf('MAC') ? 'Cmd' : 'Ctrl', addEventListener = function (e, n, cb) { e.addEventListener(n, cb, false); }; doc.documentElement.firstChild.appendChild(refStyle); if (!doc.addEventListener) { addEventListener = function (element, eventName, callback) { element.attachEvent('on' + eventName, function (e) { e.preventDefault = function () {e.returnValue = false;}; e.target = e.srcElement; callback(e); }); }; } function toggle(a, recursive) { var s = a.nextSibling || {}, oldClass = s.className, arrow, newClass; if ('sf-dump-compact' == oldClass) { arrow = '&#9660;'; newClass = 'sf-dump-expanded'; } else if ('sf-dump-expanded' == oldClass) { arrow = '&#9654;'; newClass = 'sf-dump-compact'; } else { return false; } a.lastChild.innerHTML = arrow; s.className = newClass; if (recursive) { try { a = s.querySelectorAll('.'+oldClass); for (s = 0; s < a.length; ++s) { if (a[s].className !== newClass) { a[s].className = newClass; a[s].previousSibling.lastChild.innerHTML = arrow; } } } catch (e) { } } return true; }; return function (root) { root = doc.getElementById(root); function a(e, f) { addEventListener(root, e, function (e) { if ('A' == e.target.tagName) { f(e.target, e); } else if ('A' == e.target.parentNode.tagName) { f(e.target.parentNode, e); } }); }; function isCtrlKey(e) { return e.ctrlKey || e.metaKey; } addEventListener(root, 'mouseover', function (e) { if ('' != refStyle.innerHTML) { refStyle.innerHTML = ''; } }); a('mouseover', function (a) { if (a = idRx.exec(a.className)) { try { refStyle.innerHTML = 'pre.sf-dump .'+a[0]+'{background-color: #B729D9; color: #FFF !important; border-radius: 2px}'; } catch (e) { } } }); a('click', function (a, e) { if (/\bsf-dump-toggle\b/.test(a.className)) { e.preventDefault(); if (!toggle(a, isCtrlKey(e))) { var r = doc.getElementById(a.getAttribute('href').substr(1)), s = r.previousSibling, f = r.parentNode, t = a.parentNode; t.replaceChild(r, a); f.replaceChild(a, s); t.insertBefore(s, r); f = f.firstChild.nodeValue.match(indentRx); t = t.firstChild.nodeValue.match(indentRx); if (f && t && f[0] !== t[0]) { r.innerHTML = r.innerHTML.replace(new RegExp('^'+f[0].replace(rxEsc, '\\$1'), 'mg'), t[0]); } if ('sf-dump-compact' == r.className) { toggle(s, isCtrlKey(e)); } } if (doc.getSelection) { try { doc.getSelection().removeAllRanges(); } catch (e) { doc.getSelection().empty(); } } else { doc.selection.empty(); } } }); var indentRx = new RegExp('^('+(root.getAttribute('data-indent-pad') || ' ').replace(rxEsc, '\\$1')+')+', 'm'), elt = root.getElementsByTagName('A'), len = elt.length, i = 0, t = []; while (i < len) t.push(elt[i++]); elt = root.getElementsByTagName('SAMP'); len = elt.length; i = 0; while (i < len) t.push(elt[i++]); root = t; len = t.length; i = t = 0; while (i < len) { elt = root[i]; if ("SAMP" == elt.tagName) { elt.className = "sf-dump-expanded"; a = elt.previousSibling || {}; if ('A' != a.tagName) { a = doc.createElement('A'); a.className = 'sf-dump-ref'; elt.parentNode.insertBefore(a, elt); } else { a.innerHTML += ' '; } a.title = (a.title ? a.title+'\n[' : '[')+keyHint+'+click] Expand all children'; a.innerHTML += '<span>&#9660;</span>'; a.className += ' sf-dump-toggle'; if ('sf-dump' != elt.parentNode.className) { toggle(a); } } else if ("sf-dump-ref" == elt.className && (a = elt.getAttribute('href'))) { a = a.substr(1); elt.className += ' '+a; if (/[\[{]$/.test(elt.previousSibling.nodeValue)) { a = a != elt.nextSibling.id && doc.getElementById(a); try { t = a.nextSibling; elt.appendChild(a); t.parentNode.insertBefore(a, t); if (/^[@#]/.test(elt.innerHTML)) { elt.innerHTML += ' <span>&#9654;</span>'; } else { elt.innerHTML = '<span>&#9654;</span>'; elt.className = 'sf-dump-ref'; } elt.className += ' sf-dump-toggle'; } catch (e) { if ('&' == elt.innerHTML.charAt(0)) { elt.innerHTML = '&#8230;'; elt.className = 'sf-dump-ref'; } } } } ++i; } }; })(document); </script> <style> pre.sf-dump { display: block; white-space: pre; padding: 5px; } pre.sf-dump span { display: inline; } pre.sf-dump .sf-dump-compact { display: none; } pre.sf-dump abbr { text-decoration: none; border: none; cursor: help; } pre.sf-dump a { text-decoration: none; cursor: pointer; border: 0; outline: none; }pre.sf-dump{background-color:#fff; color:#222; line-height:1.2em; font-weight:normal; font:12px Monaco, Consolas, monospace; word-wrap: break-word; white-space: pre-wrap; position:relative; z-index:100000}pre.sf-dump .sf-dump-num{color:#a71d5d}pre.sf-dump .sf-dump-const{color:#795da3}pre.sf-dump .sf-dump-str{color:#df5000}pre.sf-dump .sf-dump-cchr{color:#222}pre.sf-dump .sf-dump-note{color:#a71d5d}pre.sf-dump .sf-dump-ref{color:#a0a0a0}pre.sf-dump .sf-dump-public{color:#795da3}pre.sf-dump .sf-dump-protected{color:#795da3}pre.sf-dump .sf-dump-private{color:#795da3}pre.sf-dump .sf-dump-meta{color:#b729d9}pre.sf-dump .sf-dump-key{color:#df5000}pre.sf-dump .sf-dump-index{color:#a71d5d}</style><pre class=sf-dump id=sf-dump-1357969015 data-indent-pad="  "><abbr title="Carbon\Carbon" class=sf-dump-note>Carbon</abbr> {<a class=sf-dump-ref>#144</a><samp>
  +"<span class=sf-dump-public title="Runtime added dynamic property">date</span>": "<span class=sf-dump-str title="26 characters">2015-08-17 04:28:25.000000</span>"
  +"<span class=sf-dump-public title="Runtime added dynamic property">timezone_type</span>": <span class=sf-dump-num>3</span>
  +"<span class=sf-dump-public title="Runtime added dynamic property">timezone</span>": "<span class=sf-dump-str title="3 characters">UTC</span>"
</samp>}
</pre><script>Sfdump("sf-dump-1357969015")</script>
```

Comment: So each time you insert, it is inserting the current date not the date you selected in your form? What happens if you dd($date); in your `setPublishedAtAttribute()` mutator, is it the expected date?

Comment: That's correct. I'm setting a future date. dd($date) shows current date.

Comment: In that case it would appear the date being passed from the form is always the current date, try debugging the submitted data from the form before it gets passed to the mutator. If it is still the current date then the form isn't working properly.

Comment: I added the http response.

Comment: So for Form Data, published_at is the current date. I suppose something's wrong with my bootstrap then?

Comment: If you try to insert it without the mutator, does it still insert as the current date?